# How to prevent User to update extension of the excel file after saving

Tags: excel, vba, windows, zip

User should not be able to update excel file extension after saving it to xlsm.
Below code help to prevent save as but from desktop one can easily rename and change the extension to zip.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
Application.EnableEvents = False
  Dim vFile
  Dim strDirectoryPath As String
    
   If SaveAsUI Then
vFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("C:\Users\Noviberg\OneDrive\Desktop\111.xlsm", "Excel files (*.xlsm),*.xlsm")
   If TypeName(vFile) = "Boolean" Then
    Cancel = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
       Exit Sub  ' user cancelled
End If
   strDirectoryPath = "C:\Users\Noviberg\OneDrive\Desktop"
   If Dir(strDirectoryPath, vbDirectory) = "" Then MkDir strDirectoryPath
   ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs vFile, FileFormat:=56
   Application.EnableEvents = True
   saveProcessStarted = False
Cancel = True
     Exit Sub
   End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
 End Sub
```

Any way to prevent rename to zip after saving of xlsm file ?

Comment: you can not prevent that. password protect the workbook to deter any (valid) modifications outside excel.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is more of a windows security policies rather than something in Excel (VBA is only triggered once the file is open). I suspect you can setup windows policies that will block users from changing file extensions but that's not something that should be taken lightly. Look at all pros and cons before you start going down that road